# How to renew verbatim to Verbatim from fancyvrb?

Tags: verbatim, pandoc, fancyvrb

I am using pandoc to convert Markdown to Tex, pandoc will render code blocks to `\begin{verbatim}CODE\end{verbatim}`, and fvextra only works with `\begin{Verbatim}[breaklines]`.

How can I make `{verbatim}` to work as `{Verbatim}[breaklines]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redefine `verbatim` to use `fancyvrb` and `fvextra` options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}{breaklines}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$
la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$
la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is how to do it on LaTeX side:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\renewenvironment{verbatim}{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{Verbatim}[breaklines]%
}{%
  \end{Verbatim}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$
la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$
la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

You only need to instruct pandoc to add these lines to preamble:

```
\renewenvironment{verbatim}{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{Verbatim}[breaklines]%
}{%
  \end{Verbatim}%
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Galaxy my code had some unneeded complication, I have simplified it.