# How can I put every `verbatim` environment inside a `Shaded` environment by changing the preamble only?

Tags: macros, formatting, verbatim, framed, backgrounds

Unfortunately, I have a lot of TeX code which should look different that it does not, but I cannot modify its code body. However, I *can* modify the preamble and for example, I have learned that I can redefine `\texttt` to make every

```
\texttt{text}
```

into

```
\colorbox{shadecolor}{\texttt{text}}
```

by running

```
\let\oldtexttt\texttt
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{\colorbox{shadecolor}{\oldtexttt{#1}}}
```

in the preamble. That might not be perfect, but it works great. However, now I want to put every `verbatim` environment inside a `Shaded` environment. Obviously I cannot use `\renewcommand` for this again. Is there something else I can use to make every

```
\begin{verbatim}
text
\end{verbatim}
```

into

```
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{verbatim}
text
\end{verbatim}
\end{Shaded}
```

by changing the preamble only?

**Screenshots:**

What it looks like:

[image: screenshot]

What it *should* look like:

[image: screenshot]

**MCVE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{200,200,0}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
text
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `fancyvrb` package, using similar technique as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468250/4686

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{Goldenrod}

\renewenvironment{verbatim}{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{shaded}
  \begin{Verbatim}%
}{%
  \end{Verbatim}%
  \end{shaded}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$
la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$
la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your `fancyvrb` version is in the `3.x` series but before `3.2` of `2019/01/08` you may need to use this preamble instead:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}% loads xcolor hence option clash hence the above
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{named}{Goldenrod}
```

(or load `xcolor` with `dvipsnames` option before loading `fancyvrb`), because for these releases `fancyvrb` loaded `xcolor`.

Comment: `\def\VerbatimEnvironment{\gdef\FV@EnvironName{verbatim}}` can be more simply just `\VerbatimEnvironment`.

Answer (score 2):

With `etoolbox` it's quite easy. You can use the `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment` hooks:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{200,200,0}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{verbatim}{\begin{Shaded}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{verbatim}{\end{Shaded}}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
text
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

or, if you can't add more packages (although, chances are `etoolbox` was already loaded by another package), you can copy the relevant parts of the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{200,200,0}
\newenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{snugshade}}{\end{snugshade}}

\makeatletter
% Copied from latex.ltx
\def\begin#1{%
  \csname @beforebegin@#1@hook\endcsname% <<-- Added this
  \@ifundefined{#1}%
    {\def\reserved@a{\@latex@error{Environment #1 undefined}\@eha}}%
    {\def\reserved@a{\def\@currenvir{#1}%
     \edef\@currenvline{\on@line}%
     \csname #1\endcsname}}%
  \@ignorefalse
  \begingroup\@endpefalse\reserved@a}
\def\end#1{%
  \csname end#1\endcsname\@checkend{#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe\@doendpe\fi
  \csname @afterend@#1@hook\endcsname% <<-- Added this
  \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi}
% Copied from etoolbox.sty
\DeclareRobustCommand{\BeforeBeginEnvironment}[1]{%
  \expandafter\gappto\csname @beforebegin@#1@hook\endcsname}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\AfterEndEnvironment}[1]{%
  \expandafter\gappto\csname @afterend@#1@hook\endcsname}
\newcommand{\ifundef}[1]{%
  \ifdefined#1%
    \ifx#1\relax
      \expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
      \expandafter\expandafter
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gappto}[2]{%
  \ifundef{#1}
    {\xdef#1{\unexpanded{#2}}}
    {\xdef#1{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}\unexpanded{#2}}}}
\makeatother

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{verbatim}{\begin{Shaded}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{verbatim}{\end{Shaded}}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
text
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jayjayyy `etoolbox` is widely used, so chances are it's already loaded by some other package. Either way I copied the relevant parts of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fancyvrb` and `fvextra`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,fvextra}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{200,200,0}

\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{verbatim}{Verbatim}
{highlightlines=1-10000,highlightcolor=shadecolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$
la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$
la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$ la$
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

As far as I can see, there is no way to specify that you want to highlight all lines, so I set 10000 as the last line, which should be sufficient.

[image]